# Silverlight DataContext binding error when property is null

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml

In my Silverlight application i a have TabControl, the tab control has the following item:

```
<controls:TabItem Header="{Binding Localization.Shift1}" Style="{StaticResource     PanelBarTabItemStyle}" IsTabStop="False">
    <local:DienstDetailItemControl DataContext="{Binding Shift1, Mode=TwoWay, Converter=    {StaticResource DebugConverter}}"/>
</controls:TabItem>
```

When my application starts the Shift1 property is still null (it will be filled when the user selects an option).

I get the following error when launching my application:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: ConvertBack cannot convert value 'null' (type 'null'). BindingExpression: Path='Shift1' DataItem='SDB.Zorgplanner.Client.ViewModels.ViewModels.DienstDetailViewModel' (HashCode=13572818); target element is 'SDB.Zorgplanner.Client.Assets.Controls.DienstDetailItemControl' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'System.Object').. System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.set_Value(System.Object)' to access method 'SDB.Zorgplanner.Client.ViewModels.ViewModels.DienstDetailViewModel.set_Shift1(SDB.Zorgplanner.UIModel.Dienst)' failed.
   bij System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
   bij System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
   bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bij System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   bij System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
   bij System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.set_Value(Object value)
   bij System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.set_Value(Object value)
   bij System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateValue().
```

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Is there maybe a way to set the datacontext of the tabitems programatically from the viewmodel?

Comment: can you post the source of DebugConverter?

Comment: The DebugConverter is empty and was there to debug the values.. without it it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a private setter for the Shift1 property... i removed the private attribute and all works fine :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @RomanC This *is* the author, answering his/her own question ;-)

Comment: It might be usefull for other people that have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error, you will notice that it is thrown by the ConvertBack method. Which is unusual for a DataContext binding, which led me to notice you have a TwoWay mode binding for the DataContext. Unless you have an explicit need for a TwoWay binding, I suggest you switch to a OneWay (or just omit the mode attribute in the XAML, which does the same thing).

Comment: I indeed need the two way binding for this datacontext, it exposes properties i will be able to edit. The problem is that on startup of the application the Shift1 property is null..

Comment: The way your code is setup it means that the Shift1 property will be set when the DataContext is changed. Does the DataContext property get changed a lot and you need to keep changing the Shift1 property to match changes? Or do you just need a reference to the Shift1 property? Because if the second case is true you can access it by a code like: `var shift1reference=DataContext as TypeOfShift1Property;` `if (shift1reference!=null){DoStuff(shift1reference);}`

Comment: Also, FrameworkElement class has a DataContextChanged event that you can subscribe to track changes to that dependency property. I suggest you use that instead of TwoWay binding.

Comment: The Shift1 property changes a lot (calendar application). I could try a one way binding, and mitigate the propery changes myself, but that would be quite some work, i dont understand though why silverlight throws this error, in Silverlight V3 this did not happen, it would just ignore the null value of Shift1 and continue. The application actually works fine apart from the exception i get in debug mode... because once the Shift1 property will be filled all is fine..

Comment: In that case I would suggest using a custom converter with the TwoWay binding that would gracefully handle a null value.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the gracefull part? I wouldnt know what to return, at the moment the ConvertBack methods returns null.